# What is the best way to check if an EAV attribute exists in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav

Who would know how to check if an attribute exists in magento before adding options to it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based on what? An attribute code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
$entity = 'catalog_product';
$code = 'status';
$attr = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_attribute')
    ->loadByCode($entity,$code);

if ($attr->getId()) {
    // atttribute exists
}
```